# ImageMagick distort with increase virtual canvas

Tags: imagemagick-convert, perspective

Using ImageMagick (convert) I'm trying to create a distortion of an image that results in an image larger than the original, but only contains a subset of the original.

[image: blue is the distortion and red the sample]

However, when I perform the distort with ImageMagick, the bottom is cropped to the dimensions of the original image.  The request I'm making is this:

```
convert \
  -verbose \
   img-to-distort.png \
  -matte \
  -virtual-pixel transparent \
  -interpolate integer \
  -distort perspective '64,0 0,-4  128,0 24,8  128,96 24,112  64,96 0,128' \
   output.png
```

The original image dimensions are 128w x 96h pixels

How can I increase the virtual canvas that the distortion occurs on prior to saving?  Using `+distort` is no good, because I lose the offset etc.

Comment: Use -set option:distort:viewport WxH+X+Y. See https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#distort_viewport.

Comment: Post your input image so we can test and propose a solution. Also identify how large you want the output.

Comment: Thanks @fmw42.  I'd already solved the issue for myself satisfactorily, but didn't have time to post on here.

Answer (score 0):

So, a solution to this was to `-resize` the image prior to distortion.  Since distortion resizes anyway, there is no degradation of image.

Once distorted, we then use `-extent` to take the area of the image we want to use.

```
convert \
  -verbose \
  -resize 128x120 \
   img-to-distort.png \
  -matte \
  -virtual-pixel transparent \
  -interpolate integer \
  -distort perspective '64,0 0,-4  128,0 24,8  128,96 24,112  64,96 0,128' \
  -extent 24x120 \
   output.png
```

This worked perfectly for my needs.